# Subclass constructor initializer list for superclass members

Tags: c++, inheritance

How can I initialize data in superclass members with a subclass initializer list? This is what I want, but the symbol `name` is not found in class `Dog`:

```
class Animal  {
    public:
        virtual ~Animal() {
            delete name;
        }
        string* name;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
    public:
        Dog(string* n): name(n) { };
};
```

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't have "superclasses". They are called base classes.

Comment: Note that it makes very little sense to allocate a `string` dynamically.